# what is wrong with this JS cookie Script?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, cookies, mobile-safari

I have a code that has no syntax errors (Dreamweaver) but the Chrome JS console is saying that ExistsCookie is undefined. The cookie was in the cookie list for that site but the page is not redirecting. What am I doing wrong? NOTE: I know people can turn cookies off.

```
var cname = "voicevote"
var data ="1";


function CheckForCookie()
{
  if( ExistsCookie(cname) )
   {
     window.location.replace("cookie.htm")
   }
}
```

Comment: Where do you define `ExistsCookie`?

Comment: check this [tutorial](http://w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp) to build functions to work with cookies

Answer (score 1):

Most likely, `ExistsCookie` is a function that you haven't included in your script- if this was taken from a tutorial on some other website, look there- there may be a function on that page which you forgot to include in your code.

**EDIT:** After some googling, it looks like this is what you need:

```
function ExistsCookie(name)
 {
  var aCookie = document.cookie.split("; ");
  for (var i=0; i < aCookie.length; i++)
  {
    var aCrumb = aCookie[i].split("=");
    if (name == aCrumb[0]) 
      return true;
  }

  return false;
}
```

([Source](http://answers.google.com/answers/threadview/id/183253.html), which appears to match original question)

Comment: Iam a newbee, where do I put this in my script

Comment: @rn10950: I recommend to read this article: http://www.w3.org/wiki/Your_first_look_at_JavaScript

Comment: @m10950, put it below the script you posted in your question; so after the last curly brace, add a new line or two, and then you can copy-paste the function there.

You should definitely take a look at the article FelixKling posted above, though- it's long but it'll save you a huge amount of trouble if you plan on programming in JavaScript.